# Demand paging increases throughput without increasing turnaround time

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

In demand paging, page is read from disk into memory when it is needed by process.
This incurs the overhead of disk I/O and makes process to wait.

Now, I have read a line (from Galvin's 'Operating System Concepts' book, 'Virtual Memory' chapter) stating that Demand paging increases throughput without increasing response time or turnaround time.

I am agree that demand paging increases throughput, but how it is possible without increasing the turnaround time if it involves disk I/O?

**Example**
Consider a process submitted at time 0 to system.
Also consider that process may have to wait in device queue for variable amount of time.
Process consists of 3 pages.
Time required to read a page from disk to memory is 2ms.
Total time required to execute the process is 10ms.

Suppose that long term schedure decides to add the process in memory at time 5.

**Without Demand Paging:**

It will take 2*3=6ms to load 3 pages of process in memory.
Then process executes for 10ms.

Waiting in Job queue         5
loading process in memory    6
execute                      10
Hence TAT=5+6+10=21ms

**With demand paging:**

First page is loaded in memory in 2ms.
Then process executes for 4ms and requires next page in memory.
Hence process is added in waiting queue of disk, where it waits for 10ms and then second page is loaded in 2ms.
Then process executes for 3ms and demands third page.
Again process waits 5ms for disk and then page is loaded in 2ms.
Then process executes for 3ms and terminates.

Waiting in Job queue               5
loading 1st page                   2
execute                            4
Waiting for disk                   10
loading second page in memory      2
execute                            3
waiting for disk                   5
loading third page in memory       2
execute                            3
Hence TAT=5+2+4+10+2+3+5+2+3=36ms

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to see why **[response time](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/what-is-throughput-turnaround-time-waiting-time-and-response-time)** is not increased. Since you do not need to load the entire program from disk to main memory, definitely the response time is not increased **perhaps it is decreased** because we can begin execution with only partial loading of the program in main memory.

Now, how is the **[turnaround time](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/what-is-throughput-turnaround-time-waiting-time-and-response-time)** is not increased. Well mainly because its the **total time** consumed by process. So lets say you dont have demand paging in that case you first load the **entire program** in main memory which still requires the **disk I/O** and then begin execution. But in demand paging you load the program part by part only when its required which again requires **disk I/O**. In worst case you would have to load the entire program in main memory even in demand paging when all pages of your program would be required. Either way you are **NOT** doing any extra disk I/O, as compared to non demand paging system and hence, no increase in the turnaround time.

Comment: Thank you Sumeet! But when loading entire process in memory, process has to wait in device queue once and then entire process is loaded in memory. While in case of demand paging, process may have to wait in device queue for every request for I/O. This increases the waiting time of process.

Comment: @Kavita From the same book the definition is Turnaround time is sum of periods spent waiting to get into memory , waiting in ready queue and executing on CPU and doing I/O.

Comment: @Kavita Check out page 153 of the book.

Comment: What do you say about the time required to wait in device queue (in this case disk) before the I/O request of the process is serviced, is it considered in TAT or not?

Comment: @Kavita even when the process is not yet added in ready queue but the turnaround time is counted as said in the definition waiting to get into memory.